# HTTP API Correct HTTP status Codes and Response

Tags: rest, http-headers

I am working on a RESTful API and looking into what is the best response and HTTP status codes that should be used.

My app will be posting to the API an api key which will be used for authentication, so here I would return a `HTTP 403 Forbidden`.

They'll also be posting an ID for something that is registered, if the API key is correct, but the ID that has been posted wasn't found under their own account, should I send back `HTTP 200 OK` and then in the body have a message that says the app id is not valid. Or should I send back a different HTTP code, but I'm not sure what, I thought maybe 404 not found, but thought that this is best for an endpoint that has been requested but isn't valid.

Comment: here's a [guide](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code) for choosing the appropriate HTTP Status Code

Comment: Thanks, that's a handy guide